# ExtJs infinite-scroll grid with ajax proxy

Tags: ajax, extjs, proxy, store, infinite-scroll

I try to solve some problem but I stuck. So I want to make something like [this](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/grid/infinite-scroll.html) using not **jsonp** proxy type but **ajax** proxy type. I have some site with API I can not access source PHP code. When I set

```
verticalScrollerType: 'paginggridscroller',
invalidateScrollerOnRefresh: false,
```

for my gridpanel and

```
pageSize: 200,
buffered: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    startParam: 'offset',
    limitParam: 'count',
    url : 'https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/audio.get',
    extraParams: {
        total: 50000
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'response'
    }
}
```

for my store the grid is filled with my data but scroll do nothing (when I drag it, contents of grid did not scroll down). When I try to change proxy type with **jsonp** my data is not loading at all.

What is the correct way to make grid infinite-scroll and is it possible to make store's proxy of ajax type? And how to make it works with my custom **startParam** and **limitParam**?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `guaranteeRange(0, your_page_size-1)` instead of very first `load()`